# insert statement in nodejs for loop?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, nosql

I am trying to insert multiple values into the nosql database cassandra, using an array, but when I use the code below, instead of adding a row for each of the values stored in `foo5` it only ends up adding two rows. The two rows added contain the same value in `col5` and `col3`

```
var insert2 = "INSERT INTO content (col, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
    for(var i = 0; i < foo5.length; i++) {
        client.execute(insert2, [foo, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5[i]], {prepare : true}, function(err, result) {
            if(err) throw err;
        });
    }
```

for example this is what the result looks like(`col` is the primary key):

```
 col     | col2    | col3      | col4   | col5
---------+---------+-----------+--------+--------
 8909265 |  text   |      8759 |   5332 |   7480
 1769288 |  text   |      8759 |   5332 |   7480
```

I want to add a row for every single value in the array `foo5`. This is the expected result. How can I achieve this:

```
 col     | col2    | col3     | col4  | col5
---------+---------+-----------+--------+--------
 8909265 |  text   |      8759 |   5332 |   1234
 1769288 |  text   |      8759 |   5332 |   5678
 3254786 |  text   |      8759 |   5332 |   9101112
 4357234 |  text   |      8759 |   5332 |   1314151617
```

assuming `foo5 = {1234, 5678, 9101112, 1314151617};`

**UPDATE:**

after adding a recursive function as suggested by someRandomSerbianGuy this is what my code looks like:

```
function recursion(i, counter) {
    var insert2 = "INSERT INTO content (col, col2, col3, col4, col5) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"
    if(counter == i) {
        return;
    } else {
        client.execute(insert2, [foo, foo2, foo3, foo4, foo5[i]], {prepare : true}, function(err, result) {
            if(err) throw err;
            recursion(++i, counter);
        });
    }
}
recursion(0, foo5.length);
```

I am still getting the same results.

Comment: What is the contents of `foo5`?  (And is there any reason you can't do `for (element in foo5) { client.execute(insert2, [..., element ...  }`?

Comment: @Keith Javascript strings are immutable that wouldn't be an issue here. Regardless, using var or let here won't matter as the variable is still captured in sub-functions

Comment: On the face of it, the value of `foo` never changes ... yet `col` does.  This is not the code you're running.

Comment: @Tibrogargan this is the code that I am running. I have just changed the variable names and the column names

Comment: Um .. it can't be both the same code and have changes at the same time.  The code you posted quite literally is not going to produce the examples you give.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I see where you are coming from now the reason why the value of `col` changes is because it is a random generated number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to a promisified client module and use an async function.  You will need to research promises and async functions in Node.  It will take a bit of time getting used to it, but is necessary because this type of problem happens all the time with callbacks.

Code will be simpler, and it will work in a more straightforward way, with one insert at a time:

```
async function insert(sql, data) {
  for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    await client.insert(sql, data[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because Node.js is asynchronous. You can use Promises for this, or recursive function instead for loop.

By using recursive function instead for loop you are enabling it to finish `client.execute` and than triggering it again with different data. By using for loop you are just calling `client.execute` bunch of times with same data.

Example (for recursion in Node.js, be aware that there are better ways to write this, but I wanted to make it simple so you would understand syntax):

```
function recursion(i, howManyTimes){ //First you define function
    if(i === howManyTimes){ //If it's called enough times just escape recursion
        return;
    }else{
        //Your code for DB should be here, after successful .execute call call line under this one!
        recursion(++i, howManyTimes);
    }
}
recursion(0, 5); //You can call your function now since you defined it
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Comment: @N00B I added example for recursion in my answer.